# Do these rules fully define when to throw exceptions?

Tags: exception

1. If a method fails to do what it says it will do (e.g. if `SendEmail` fails to send an email), it should throw an exception.  I blogged about this in-depth (optional read): [Do your work, or throw an exception - example](http://abstractions-r-us.blogspot.com/2010/06/do-your-work-or-throw-exception-example.html).  It seems this idea is already a convention, even though I have not found it described elsewhere.  "Exceptions are for exceptional cases" is a different guideline requiring an additional guideline "Do not use exceptions for normal flow control", and requiring discussion on what is "exceptional".  "Do your work or throw an exception" is as unambiguous as the responsibility of the method (which already should be unambiguous).
2. All methods, including "Try" methods (e.g. `TrySendEmail`), should always throw if some unrecoverable error happens--something that adversely affects *other* features of the app, not just the functionality being attempted, such as RamChipExplodedException.  That is, even though "TrySendEmail" technically accomplishes what the name indicates (it *tries* to send an email), it should still throw an exception if the RAM explodes (if it can even do that... you get my drift).
3. "Try" methods should be used only in special cases.

Are these *always* good guidelines (i.e., are there any exceptions (pun!) to the rule)?  Can you think of any others not covered by these?

To clarify, I'm not asking for more specific rules of thumb to help follow these guidelines; I'm looking for additional guidelines.

Comment: Asking for definition without attempting definition is a bit like chucking a pebble on water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the #1 rule is: avoid exceptions in normal flow. When you debug, make sure all thrown exceptions are signalled. It is the first indication that your code is working the way you designed it.

TryXXX should not throw exceptions unless you violate the design contract. So for instance TrySendMail() may throw if you pass in a null pointer as the text for the email. 
You need TryXXX methods if there is no way to get "normal flow" exception free without them. So for parsing data, they're essential, I would not reccomend a `TryLogin` function.

"Do your work or throw" is a good starting point, but I would not make it a dogma. I am OK with a collection returning -1 if you ask `IndexOf` an item that isn't there. You can discuss with your colleages where you want to draw the line and put in your coding standards.

I also use exceptions a lot to label control paths that I think are not used. For instance if I am forced to write a `GetHashCode` function that I assume won't be called, I make it throw.

Comment: These are good points.  I think all of these fall under the rules given above.  Even IndexOf returning -1 for an item that was not found is doing its work if its documentation says it will return -1 in such cases.

Comment: I would posit that a `TryXX` method should throw an exception if it fails *for any reason other than what the caller would expect*.  If while executing a `TryGetValue`, a `Dictionary` discovers that it has been corrupted (e.g. by simultaneous accesses on two threads) it should not merely return false--it should throw an exception, because the caller will interpret a `false` return as saying that the key either was not added, or was last deleted since it was last added; if the structure is corrupt, those statements may not be true.

Comment: @supercat: I agree. Try should not hide real problems. Do consider that it we cant always guess what a user expects. Consider writing a `TryLogin`: Some may expect it to throw when the authentication server could not be reached. Some may expect that it would return `false`. If such ambigueties exist, the behaviour should be documented, or one should not write a `TryXxx` API.

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan: If the method is supposed to start by creating a connection from scratch, I would use `ConnectAndTryLogin` or `TryConnectAndLogin` to distinguish whether the caller expects that the connection itself might fail.  As for the authentication server, offer a `CheckAuthenticationAvailability` method.  Authentication should generally be expected to work; situations where it would fail after having been confirmed as available would be rare enough to justify using `Try`/`Catch`

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental goal of efficient and effective exception handling strategy is for a method to throw exceptions for situations the caller isn't prepared to handle, while letting the caller handle things it is prepared for without the overhead of throwing an exception.

Since functions cannot be clairvoyant with regard to caller expectations, the usual pattern is to have multiple versions of routines where different callers may have different expectations.  Someone who decides to call Dictionary.GetValue indicates an expectation that the passed-in key exists in the dictionary.  By contrast, someone who calls Dictionary.TryGetValue conveys an expectation that the key may or may not be in a dictionary--either would be reasonably expected.  Even in that case, however, the caller probably isn't expecting the CPU to catch fire.  If a CpuCaughtFireException occurs in the processing of TryGetValue, it should probably be allowed to propagate up the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't get too hung up about the name "exception" and what exactly is and is not an exceptional situation.

Exceptions are simply another flow control statement, one that allows the flow of control to shortcut up the call stack.

If that's what you need (i.e. you expect immediate calling methods not to be able to handle the condition usefully), use an exception. Otherwise, don't.